# Add Button listener with delegate to stop updating method argument

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, delegates

Suppose I have a canvas in Unity and I want to create 5 buttons in it. Every time I press a button, it will state `This is button n.i`, where `i` goes from 0 to 4. This is the code I've been using so far:

```
public Button buttonPrefab; //set from inspector
void SetButtons()
{
    Button newObj;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    { //loop 5 times, creates a button using buttonPrefab and assign ButtonNumber() method to it
        newObj = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, transform);
        newObj.onClick.AddListener(delegate { ButtonNumber(i); });
    }
}
void ButtonNumber(int nButton)
{
    Debug.Log($"This is button n.{nButton}");
}
```

I use `onClick.AddListener` to assign a Method to the button, and since the Method requires argument I've been passing them using `delegate`.

The problem is that, for every button I press, the result is always `This is button n.5`.

All buttons always seem to be updating according to the latest value of `i`, even though I'd want the Methods to save the `i` value at the time it was assigned.

I could make the script work by using this script:

```
public Button buttonPrefab; //set from inspector
void SetButtons()
{
    Button newObj;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        newObj = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, transform);
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                newObj.onClick.AddListener(delegate { ButtonNumber(0); });
                break;
            case 1:
                newObj.onClick.AddListener(delegate { ButtonNumber(1); });
                break;
            case 2:
                newObj.onClick.AddListener(delegate { ButtonNumber(2); });
                break;
            case 3:
                newObj.onClick.AddListener(delegate { ButtonNumber(3); });
                break;
            case 4:
                newObj.onClick.AddListener(delegate { ButtonNumber(4); });
                break;
        }
    }
}
void ButtonNumber(int nButton)
{
    Debug.Log($"This is buton n.{nButton}");
}
```

But I wouldn't call it a "smart" solution.

Is there anything I can do to make the buttons work in the first script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change to:

```
  var x = i;
  newObj.onClick.AddListener(delegate { ButtonNumber(x); });
```

Voila.

What's going on is called "capturing" of the i variable, and you can find tons of questions and answers on it, for example:
[Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I feel so stupid for not having tried that! Thank you so much.

Comment: No need to. Bright programmers have even blogged about finding a c# bug when they encountered this for the first time! You're in good company! :-)

Comment: I'm curious, is this an *intended* feature? It looks like it could lead to more errors than benefits. Where can it be beneficial?

Comment: Few things in this world is so thoroughly well-reasoned as the C# specifications, so yes, it is intended. And, yes, this has baffled many programmers. May I suggest this for further reading: https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/